# Как защитить сервер от внесения изменений через чужие ajax запросы?

Tags: php, ajax, сервер, безопасность, защита

Сервер работает на PHP, хочу чтобы при оплате у клиента возникала возможность добавить изменения в один из файлов этого сервера. Я предпологал что это возможно, путём отправки Ajax запроса в определенный php файл, несущего ряд параметров, которые пользователь вводит.  И что этот файл как раз и будет вносить нужные изменения, с  полученными параметрами на сервер, в нужном месте и т.д
Но на сколько это безопасно? Разве не сможет любой другой "хакер" отправить на этот php-файл свой ajax, избегая оплаты за внесение тзменений на сервер. Как этого избежать. Я не очень понимаю, как сделать проход процедуры оплаты неизбежным. Объясните...

Comment: Ну так пусть php-файл просто проверяет, что текущий пользователь проводил оплату?

Comment: @andreymal Типа сессией?

Comment: Это уже вы сами решайте, как вы будете идентифицировать пользователей и как вы хотите проверять факт выполнения оплаты

Comment: @andreymal, понятно, хорошо. Просто хотелось узнать, вдруг есть какие то стандартные методы проверки, или передачи информации серверу.

Comment: CORS, токены, IP...